# Does System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient use SSL, TLS, StartTLS, or a combination?

Tags: .net, ssl, smtp, smtpclient, starttls

This question has answers about negotiating the best version of TLS/SSL available with the server: [Which versions of SSL/TLS does System.Net.WebRequest support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414424/which-versions-of-ssl-tls-does-system-net-webrequest-support)

However I thought SmtpClient used regular Smtp for transport, with TLS on top - which as I understand it is StartTLS.

I am documenting some software (a box ticking exercise) and need to state which protocols are used, and security protocols are really not my area of expertise so how can I explain this well?

Answer (score 10):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl(v=vs.110).aspx) it can only do explicit TLS (i.e. STARTTLS) and not implicit TLS (SMTPS):

> The SmtpClient class **only** supports the SMTP Service Extension for
>   Secure SMTP over Transport Layer Security as defined in RFC 3207. In
>   this mode, the SMTP session begins on an unencrypted channel, then a
>   **STARTTLS** command is issued by the client to the server to switch to
>   secure communication using SSL. See RFC 3207 published by the Internet
>   Engineering Task Force (IETF) for more information.