# HttpWebRequest fails with TLS 1.2

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tls1.2

A minimal, replicable working example under .NET 4.6.1,

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
WebRequest.Create("https://ir.netflix.com/").GetResponse();
```

produces the following WebException,

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Just visiting the page myself, running `openssl s_client -connect ir.netflix.com:443 -tls1_2`, or going over the [SSL Labs analysis summary](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ir.netflix.com) suggest that the server is running proper TLS 1.2. HttpWebRequest does seem to work for TLS 1.2 some of the time (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29221439/235908)),

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
WebRequest.Create("https://www.ssllabs.com:10303").GetResponse();
```

Disabling certificate validation using `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` (either globally or local to the request object) never invokes the callback; I suppose it never reaches this far,

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://ir.netflix.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
request.GetResponse();
```

**Update:** Going over the [Wireshark dumps](https://gist.github.com/sshine/b534f45b50514abbd4cc99855e58811a) suggests common signature hash algorithms (SHA256 with RSA, SHA1 with RSA), and a common cipher suite `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` (0x000a). Besides the initial two "Client Hello" and "Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done" packets, no further contact is made from the client.

**Question:** What could be the cause for this failure? Is there a way to access more debug information for the HttpWebRequest object?

*(Disabling TLS 1.2 like this,*

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
WebRequest.Create("https://ir.netflix.com/").GetResponse();
```

*works, but is suboptimal, as it disables TLS 1.2 globally. There doesn't seem to be a setting that only disables TLS 1.2 for a single HttpWebRequest.)*

Comment: You will have to capture packets using Wireshark and then analyze the TLS handshakes. Only that can indicates why the connection is refused.

Comment: @LexLi: I'm not an expert at analysing [these dumps](https://gist.github.com/sshine/b534f45b50514abbd4cc99855e58811a), but it seems that there are common denominators in cipher suites and signature hashing algorithms. Is there a way to debug the HttpWebRequest object further? Any chance this has to do with root certificates?

Comment: As Wireshark is so famous and its design is so simple, you can easily make yourself a master, by following great guides such as https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL (tons of others on Google).

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution i am facing the same issue

Comment: Hi did you find a solution??

Comment: I didn't find a solution, and I'm not currently investigating.