# How to test which version of TLS my .NET client is using?

Tags: .net, fiddler, wireshark, packet-sniffers, tls1.2

I support a .NET site which (amongst many, MANY, other things) talks to remote APIs from supplier systems.

We want to upgrade to support TLS 1.2
We're hoping to do so as per this question: [Are there .NET implementation of TLS 1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137106/are-there-net-implementation-of-tls-1-2)

But how do I check that this is actually working once I've made the change.

Ideally one of my supplier sites would start using TLS 1.2 **ONLY** and then my test could just be "can we talk to that supplier now?" But we don't have that.
I'm guessing I can do something with a packet sniffer of some sort, but I wouldn't know what I was looking for exactly, nor how to set up the sniffer to be collecting the neccessary data in a readable manner.

Either:

- Can someone point me in the direction of a comprehensive guide to how to collect that data in Fiddler/WireShark

Or

- Can someone advise an alternative way to test that the change has worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you capture the connection creation in Wireshark, and examine the first packet from the client, then Wireshark will annotate the fields in the `ClientHello` struct for you, including the TLS version requested by the client.

Similarly, if you look at the first reply packet from the server, then Wireshark will annotate the fields in the `ServerHello` struct for you, including the TLS version settled on for the connection.

See [this blog post](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html) or [this one](http://albertx.mx/blog/https-handshake/) for worked examples.

Answer (score 60):

If you turn on "**CONNECTS**" in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), you can see the TLS/SSL version in Inspectors -> TextView

[image: Screen Capture of TLS Version 1.2 Connect to Google.com]

---

To turn on Connects, go to `Rules` in the menu bar and *remove* the check from "Hide CONNECTs"

[image: turn on connects screenshot]

*Note:* Decrypt HTTPs traffic must be **disabled**

[image: disable decrypt https traffic options screenshot]

Reference: [Viewing HTTPS Handshakes in Fiddler](https://textslashplain.com/2015/10/12/viewing-https-handshakes-in-fiddler/)

Comment: Should be noted that "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" needs to be disabled for this to work. Mentions it in the article linked to, but that could vanish I guess.

Comment: Fiddler doesn't support TLS 1.3, so it can not be checked anyway.

Answer (score 10):

The System.Net tracing does include sufficient detail to check this, although it's not very accessible.

[This KB describes how to turn on System.Net tracing.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/947285)

[This blog post shows a full HTTPS request in System.Net tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/471003.aspx).

The bytes sent over the wire are logged, and in the example given on that blog post, the client stream starts:

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3848] Data from Socket#48285313::Send
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [3848] 00000000 : 16 03 00 00 41 01 00 00-3D 03 00 43 26 02 90 83 : ....A...=..C&...
```

RFC5246 describes TLS 1.2 and [explains that ClientHello is the first message expected and states its format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2):

```
  struct {
      ProtocolVersion client_version;
      Random random;
      SessionID session_id;
      CipherSuite cipher_suites<2..2^16-2>;
      CompressionMethod compression_methods<1..2^8-1>;
      select (extensions_present) {
          case false:
              struct {};
          case true:
              Extension extensions<0..2^16-1>;
      };
  } ClientHello;
```

[This SO answer explains](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/34783/8807) that the record starts with 0x16 as a type marker, then the protocol version.

The session shown above has version 3.0, [which means SSL 3.0](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785811(v=ws.10).aspx).

[The RFC explains](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-E) that 3.3 is TLS 1.2.

So if your client data starts "`16 03 03`", then your client is attempting to negotiate TLS 1.2.

You may need to examine the ServerHello to establish which version was actually used.

Answer (score 4):

If you make a HTTP GET request to https://check-tls.akamai.io/v1/tlsinfo.json it will respond with the TLS version used in the client request, for example;

```
var http = new HttpClient();
const string url = "https://check-tls.akamai.io/v1/tlsinfo.json";
var result = http.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The TLS/SSL version can also be probed and determined using the curl tool https://curl.se/ as shown below.

[image]

The command

```
curl -v -k https://host:port --tlsv1.1 --tls-max 1.1
```

sends a https GET request to the host using a specific TLS minimum and maximum version. So the above command forces the client and server to use TLS 1.1. You can see from the output that this fails with error message

> SSL_ERROR_PROTOCOL_VERSION_ALERT

the reason for this error is that the host is configured to use TLS minimum version 1.2

The second command marked in green succeeded cause client and server both support TLS v1.2

Answer (score 0):

Using below simple method and you can get answer of TLS version your Web App is using . **NOT Require** code , RunTime or Adv networking tool.

[image]