# How to find TLS version used to call an APIs

Tags: api, ssl, fiddler, tls1.2

I am trying to find out the TLS version used while calling third party APIs, I have captures these API request/response through fiddler but its not showing the TLS version used in this request.
I have followed the below link:
[How to test which version of TLS my .Net client is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276358/how-to-test-which-version-of-tls-my-net-client-is-using?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

As per above link, the TLS version can be found in TextView.
Below is the snapshot what it showing to me in TextView:
[image: Fiddler Snapshot]

Any help in this regards will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using WireShark? https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: Apparently if you go to the Rules menu and desselect Hide CONNECTs, it will show you the tls version.

Comment: I have already tried it with both "Hide CONNECTs" selected and un-selected, but it shows same results.

Comment: A CONNECT only occurs if the TCP connection was closed. Therefore for enforcing a CONNECT you have to restart the application or Fiddler.

Comment: Keep in mind that the TLS version used by the destination depends also on the client! When A calls B over https then both A and B negotiate which TLS version they will use, usually they use the highest common supported version by both A and B.