# Fiddler v4.6 Doesn't show SSL version

Tags: .net, ssl, fiddler

I want to view the SSL version used in the request and response but in Fidder it doesn't show the version attribute in Raw view in Inspector.
I have ensure Connects Rule is enabled as per :
[How to test which version of TLS my .Net client is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276358/how-to-test-which-version-of-tls-my-net-client-is-using)

Any ideas?

Here's what my response looks like :

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: 0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Persistent-Auth: true
Date: Mon, 25 Jun 2018 14:45:42 GMT
Content-Length: 629

{"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJyb2xlIjpbIk15RGVhbFVzZXIiLCJBY2Nlc3NBcHByb3ZlciIsIkRlYWxUZWFtIiwiRGVhbEFkbWluIiwiSW50ZXJuYWwiXSwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiIzIiwiaXNJbnRlcm5hbFVzZXIiOnRydWUsImdpdmVuX25hbWUiOiJSdWJhbiBTaXZhIiwic2Vzc2lvbklkIjoiNjcyNzgyZGUtODQ0Yi00ZWNhLTkzZjUtNzk1YWRkMTE5NmNkIiwiaXNEQ01Vc2VyIjp0cnVlLCJpc0VDTVVzZXIiOnRydWUsIndpbmFjY291bnRuYW1lIjoiaGJldVxcc2l2YXJ1YmEiLCJIU0JDU3RhZmZJZCI6IjQ0MDM3NDg3IiwiaXNzIjoiTXlEZWFsLURldiIsImF1ZCI6Ik15RGVhbC1EZXYiLCJleHAiOjE1Mjk5MzgxMjMsIm5iZiI6MTUyOTkzNzk0M30.Gq0sWGyzE986urd3PoVsM64BMsNzdkf9OnExFhTbd48","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":179.63785779999998}

Comment: You'll find the TLS version in the handshake messages, not the HTTP requests. SSL/TLS establishes a *channel* through which the HTTP messages pass. The parameters used to establish that channel appear on the SSL-related messages

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When you mean handshake, do you mean the response window?

Comment: On the contrary, I mean that inspecting the request/response is the *wrong* thing to inspect. By the time the request is made the SSL channel is already established and transparent to the request itself. Before the first request is made you'll see a grayed-out entry with `Tunnel to` in the host field and the target DNS name in the URL field. When you check *that* message you'll see the SSL information in the `Raw` inspector

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, I see what you mean now. Initially I had edited the HTTPs versions so wasn't showing the actual handshake messages but I reset it back to <client>;ssl3;tls1.0 and now can see it.