# How do I determine whether I need to upgrade the dot net framework given change to TLS version?

Tags: tls1.2, myob

[MYOB has advised that](http://myobapi.tumblr.com/post/177017431449/tls10-no-longer-supported) as of 30th September 2018 the MYOB API will no longer accept connections using TLS1.0

I have a Winforms application which connects to MYOB Accountright via the API using the [SDK](https://github.com/MYOB-Technology/AccountRight_Live_API_.Net_SDK)

I am wondering if there are any specific changes that I need to make to an application that I released 2 years ago.

I asked [on the developer forum](https://community.myob.com/t5/MYOB-API-questions-and-answers/Ending-TLS1-0-support-for-MYOB-API/td-p/535376) and was told that if my code uses TLS1.0 I need to change it.

From [this question about determining the dot net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460982/determine-net-framework-version-for-dll?tab=oldest#tab-top)  I am thinking that I need to check the framework MYOB.AccountRight.SDK.dll uses.
Looking in my project I see that it is v4.0.30319

I opened MYOB.AccountRight.SDK.dll in notepad and saw NETFramework,Version=v4.5

From [Stan Tarnovskly's blog](https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/28/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/)  I see

> .NET 4.5. TLS 1.2 is supported, but it’s not a default protocol. You
>   need to opt-in to use it. The following code will make TLS 1.2
>   default, make sure to execute it before making a connection to secured
>   resource: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
>   SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276358/how-to-test-which-version-of-tls-my-net-client-is-using

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276358/how-to-test-which-version-of-tls-my-net-client-is-using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to be using TLS 1.0 or 1.1 these days.

This doc has some best practices and also several references to the upgrade path you should be looking at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

> We recommend that you:
>
> - Target .NET Framework 4.7 or later versions on your apps.
> - Target .NET
>     Framework 4.7.1 or later versions on your WCF apps.
> - Do not specify
>     the TLS version. Configure your code to let the OS decide on the TLS
>     version.
> - Perform a thorough code audit to verify you're not
>     specifying a TLS or SSL version.