# SSL Handshake fails from asp.net application - works in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl

I am trying to do a simple get request using the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` (using `GetStringAsync`). The request fails when done from my webapi asp.net application, but it works correctly from the browser and postman.

The request fails with `Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.`

> Note: It works correctly when doing get request to other servers using TLS.

I used the following to confirm that the issue was with ssl. Using these two lines makes the request work, but obviously disabling certificate validation is not a real solution.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

> I tested the server using https://www.ssllabs.com and it seems that
>   everything is working correctly on there. It supports TLS 1.1 and 1.2.

To find out what is going on I was looking at the packages in wireshark, but since I don't know much about ssl, I am not learning much. Looking at the packages from the browser request I can see that it is using the TLS 1.2 protocol and that the handshake looks correct.
The following picture shows the client initiating two separate ssl "ClientHello's". For some reason the server doesn't respond with a SSL handshake response.

[image: Wireshark ssl handshake]

Hope someone can help me figure out what is going on.

Comment: Is webapi hosted using TLS with same certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tested the server using https://www.ssllabs.com and it seems that everything is working correctly on there. It supports TLS 1.1 and 1.2.

Your client is doing a TLS 1.0 handshake only. If the server supports only TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 but not TLS 1.0 the connection will fail. Since modern browsers all support TLS 1.2 browsers will work.

Comment: You are right. The request from the HttpClient will by default only use older versions of SSL / TLS. See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29221917/2227019) for more details. As described in my original question I did try the linked solution, but for some reason it didn't work then, must have had something else messing it up.