# Accessing WCF service running on the server with TLS 1.2 only enabled

Tags: wcf, ssl, wcf-security, tls1.2, fips

We have a WCF service running on Windows server with TLS 1.0 and 1.1 disabled.
Is it possible to connect to this service from Windows 7 client without TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 does support TLS 1.2.  However, you MUST use .NET 4.5 or above to use TLS 1.2.

Sources: S/O - [Are there .NET implementation of TLS 1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137106/are-there-net-implementation-of-tls-1-2)

More detail about .NET versions and TLS: http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/