# Cannot create SSL/TLS connection in vb when trying to obtain IPv4 address

Tags: vb.net, ssl, system.net.webexception

I am writing a program in my computer science class and I have come across an error when trying to obtain the public IPv4 address of the computer.

This is my code:

```
Private Function GetMyIP() As Net.IPAddress
    Using wc As New Net.WebClient

        Return Net.IPAddress.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.DownloadData("http://tools.feron.it/php/ip.php")))


    End Using
End Function
```

This is then called using this code:

```
tboxPublicIPv4.Text = GetMyIP().ToString
```

However, when it tries to write the IPv4 address to the textbox I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you're calling is redirecting to https, and it seems at least `TLS 1.1` is required.

You can enable `TLS 1.1` or `TLS 1.2` for Net.WebClient by setting the security-protocol with `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`.

Furthermore you can use `DownloadString` instead of converting the downloaded data to a string.

I would also wrap it inside a `Try/Catch`.

```
Function GetMyIP() As Net.IPAddress
    Using wc As New Net.WebClient
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        Try
            Return Net.IPAddress.Parse(wc.DownloadString("https://tools.feron.it/php/ip.php"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return New Net.IPAddress(0)
        End Try
    End Using
End Function
```

> `.NET 4.0` supports up to `TLS 1.0` while `.NET 4.5` or higher
>   supports up to `TLS 1.2` 
> For reference:
>
> - [Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)
> - [Are there .NET implementation of TLS 1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137106/are-there-net-implementation-of-tls-1-2)

Comment: I am now getting a System.NullReferenceException with additional info of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". This occurs at line 36. tboxPublicIPv4.Text = GetmyIP().ToString