# VB. NET: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: vb.net

I have an application coded in VB.net that has this method of accessing Webservice, i have this error and after searching fixes i still have no luck.

Error:
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

```
    'ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
    'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

    Dim ErrMsg As String = String.Empty

    Try

        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

        Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8)

            Return reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    Catch ex As WebException

        ErrMsg = ex.Message.ToString
        MsgBox(ErrMsg)

        Dim errorResponse As WebResponse = ex.Response
        Using responseStream As Stream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream()
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))
            ' log errorText
            Dim errorText As [String] = reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
        Throw
    End Try
```

This is my code and I'm using VS2015 and Windows 10.

All help are really appreciated. TIA

Comment: Maybe the webservice requires TLS 1.1/1.2?

Comment: Yes Mat i think the problem here circles in this code: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls

Comment: Thanks Mat, i tried that solution and yes it works, I created an new project targeting the 4.5 framework, the challenge now is that my Project is targeting 4.0 framework and a bunch of errors occurs when I change it to 4.5.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72205024/issues-making-a-tls-1-2-request-with-net-framework-4-7/72216999#72216999

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obviously the URL you're calling requires `TLS 1.1` or `TLS 1.2`.

You can enable `TLS 1.1` or `TLS 1.2` by setting the security-protocol with `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

> `.NET 4.0` supports up to `TLS 1.0` while `.NET 4.5` or higher
>   supports up to `TLS 1.2` 
> For reference:
>
> - [Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)
> - [Are there .NET implementation of TLS 1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137106/are-there-net-implementation-of-tls-1-2)

Comment: For a public portal, I had to check if stored urls still work with System.Net.WebRequest. Thereby I have noted, that calls with http crash, when the site was updated to https in the meantime (whereby a browser handles this automatically). With your answer it now works.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had to change Target Framework in project properties(Right click on Project on solution explorer->properties->Application) to 4.6.1 to use this

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add something here in case it helps others.  I have to support some legacy code that is written in VB.Net and targets .NET Framework 4.6.1.  The same piece of code runs in both an .exe, and in IIS as a web page.

In the website, this call:

```
Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
```

would throw this exception

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

but it worked fine in the .exe.

Forcing the TLS protocol fixed it in the website.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Of course if the host ever deems TLS 1.2 unworthy I'll have to fix/recompile/redeploy, but it solved the error for now.

Answer (score -1):

for vb.net 4.0 this worked for me:
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(&HC0 Or &H300 Or &HC00, SecurityProtocolType)